# Select rows from the array of another select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

The schema is as follows:

```
create table users (
    id      text constraint users_pk primary key,
    followers     text[]
);
```

`users.followers` contains an array of `id`s in string format.

I want to select those users who are the followers of a certain user, but the following SQL don't not work:

```
select * 
from users
where id in (
    select followers::text[]
    from users
    where id = '12345678'
);
```

OR

```
select * 
from users
where id = any (
    select followers::text[]
    from users
    where id = '2219144865'
);
```

Both gives the error `ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = text[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better of changing your schema: if your `id`'s are numbers, use

```
create table users(
    id serial not null primary_key
    -- other fields
);
```

and add a `followers` table that contains one row per follower:

```
create table followers (
    user_id      int not null references users(id), 
    follower_id  int not null references users(id),
    unique (user_id, follower_id)
);
```

and then you can simply select the followers for user with id X like this:

```
select * from users
where id in (select follower_id from followers where user_id = X)
```

Relational databases are very good at managing relationships, but you have to use the functionality that they provide for this: tables, rows, foreign keys, and indexes. 
It is typically bad practice to store lists of ID's in a column, because that requires special code to split such a `text` column up into separate ID's. This code must be run for every row in your resultset, slowing things down enormously. 
PostgreSQL does have extensive support for [`array` columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html), but not all databases do (MySQL for instance, does not). It is a PostgreSQL specific feature, and that tells you that this is not the common way to manage relationships in an [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system).

Using the two-table approach above, the SQL database can operate very efficiently. For instance, since `users.id` is a primary key, it is optimized for looking up records by `id`, using internal hashes.

As a rule of thumb, whenever you have a list or collection of things, you'll want to store them using one row per 'thing'.

Another down side of using arrays here is that the database cannot guarantee that the values in `followers` actually point to existing users. As far as the database is concerned, it is just a string. By specifying a `foreign key` the database will ensure data integrity, that is, you cannot store follower id's that do not exist.

You shouldn't worry about space. The `text[]` array approach might even use more space than using a second table. You can think of the `text[]` as a 'nested table' inside the `users` table. It would have to store the number and the length of the entries. In practice it won't make much of a difference.
The benefits of using a relationship table like `followers` far outweigh any concerns about space you might have. This is how RDBMS are meant to operate, and they are very efficient in how they do it.

Comment: So you suggested not to store the `followers` in an array but to flatten them in a table. What are the advantages? Will the new  `followers` table grow to very large?  (I came from NoSQL)

Comment: Updated the answer with an explanation. I hope it makes some sense!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the reason for the error is that the inner `select` query does not return just an array, but a set of arrays. Every `followers` is an array by itself, and the `select` returns many arrays of `followers`. An ID is then not a member of the resulting set, because an ID is a text, not an array.

You need to concatenate them into one big array, and then you can check whether the uses exists there or not. So I would suggest something like the following (I'm not sure the syntax is right):

```
select * 
from users
where id in array_cat(
    select followers::text[]
    from users
    where id = '12345678'
);
```

Comment: Sorry it still doesnt work, and I think I better follow @kenney 's advice not to use array ;) Thanks!

Comment: I agree, I like his answer too.